# How to track OOM shutdowns in iOS once Fabric Crashlytics is gone in April 2020?

Tags: ios, firebase, out-of-memory, crashlytics

OOM shutdowns happen when the app is killed by the OS - these do not show up as crashes in crash-reporting systems, even though they are just as bad from a user perspective.

To track OOMs, you must eliminate all possible sources of app closure (user closed the app, app was upgraded, OS was upgraded, et cetera), and if none of those happened, you have an OOM. This technique is all laid out in this Facebook Engineering blog post:

https://engineering.fb.com/ios/reducing-fooms-in-the-facebook-ios-app/

Currently we use Fabric Crashlytics to track crashes and OOM events, like many others. Fabric Crashlytics is going away as of April 2020 and has been replaced with Firebase Crashlytics. As of this tweet, Firebase has no plans to implement OOM tracking.

https://twitter.com/Arzhannikov_A/status/1073194994134065152

Implementing code to check whether the app was force-closed etc is quite simple, except when it comes to detecting a crash in the previous run of the app. As far as I can tell the only way to do it is to implement PLCrashReporter and track myself whether the system encountered a crash.

It seems bananas to me that Firebase wouldn't implement this feature that is so critical to providing metrics around app shutdowns, but that's the world we live in. Is there a better way to do this or an existing library that doesn't rely on Fabric Crashlytics to work?